# How can I install two different licenses of Office365 that co-exist on a Mac at the same time?

Tags: office-365, installation, licensing, mac-os-x

I've got to do stuff for two different organisations that each have their own licensing. They also control and manage plugins separately.

So far, I've used logins to switch between them in apps like Word and PowerPoint, but I've run into a problem where the second org (not the currently installed license) have approved a plugin for word that I can't install b/c the licence installed on my Mac is a different key.

I'd like to have two "buckets" of office 365 apps on my computer (one for each key) and just swap between them.

Is this possible? How can I solve this?

Answer (score 0):

This isn't possible. You would need to have the second organization approve the addin, depending on that organization's configuration for Office.

Comment: Well that’s a depressing answer...